# Batch call to API some responses are returning invalid JSON response body

Tags: javascript, json

I have a for each statement which is taking a stock market symbol and running it through a function which fires off a fetch call to retrieve data regarding the symbol.

When running my app I'm getting this returned back in my console.

> Error with CACFetchError: invalid json response body at https‍://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=CAC&types=quote,chart&range=1d&chartInterval=30 reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

It would suggest that the response isn't JSON but you can see by visiting it that it is correct and no '<' arrow exists at position 0.

`https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=CAC&types=quote,chart&range=1d&chartInterval=30`

I'm at a loss on what could be causing this. I've tried setting a timeout delay in case there is a limit on the API, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of message is a strong indication that the response is probably HTML and not JSON. Recheck the api endpoint to which you request. And also make sure that the api sends back JSON. Use postman to view the response from api

Edit: also did you call the `json()` function on the response that you got?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As you can see on the endpoint link above it is valid JSON that is returned and yes I can confirm that I have `.then(res=>res.json())` chained onto my fetch

Comment: Try to console.log the response in the code. Probably something going wrong with the request. Also is the response status 200? Edit: to console.log response without any errors, remove the call to `json()` temporarily.

Comment: Thanks. Everything seems fine when requesting the end points individually. I'm thinking it's because I have 8000+ requests that it's either timing out or bottle necking. Is there a way that I could add on a delay between the requests? I've tried wrapping in a setTimeout function but it doesnt seem to be having an effect. Code is here: https://github.com/alienbuild/node_alienSOI/blob/master/symbols/symbol.js

Comment: Can you provide the code where you use this symbol function that you exported?

Comment: It's in the app.js file. It just iterates through the symbols and saves to mongodb (line 67)
https://github.com/alienbuild/node_alienSOI/blob/master/app.js

Comment: Also, that probably isn't a way to really add delay to subsequent requests. The anonymous function inside the exported function will be delayed by 4 seconds but if lets say you ran symbol() inside a loop, if first call to symbol occurs at x seconds, js schedules call to inner function at x+4 seconds and moves ahead. Next call to symbol() occurs at x seconds+ some nano seconds, hence the delay between two requests is still the same. I hope you got my point

Comment: Thank you. Managed to get it working following your guidance. Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad i could help